# How to bind array index to DataGrid row index?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have class `InvoiceItem`

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    private string item_name;
    private string mesure;
    private float quantity;
    private float price_exc_VAC;
    private float VAC;
    private float price_inc_Vac;
    private float total;

    //Properties
}
```

And another class `Invoice` that contains array of `InvoiceItems`

```
 public class Invoice
{

    private InvoiceItem [] items = new InvoiceItem[100];
    private string supplier;
    private string supplierBank;
    private int supplierAccount;

    private string buyer;
    private string buyerBank;
    private int buyerAccount;
    private string shipping_adress;

    //Properties
    }
```

I'm using MVVM pattern (don't know if correctly) and I have `ItemViewModel`

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Invoice invoice = new InvoiceItem();

    public ItemViewModel(string tabName)
    {
        TabName = tabName;
    }

    public string TabName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

   //example of one of the properties inside

    public string Supplier
    {
        get
        {
            return invoice.supplier;
        }

        set
        {
            if (invoice.supplier != value)
            {
                invoice.supplier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Supplier");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

ObservableCollection's

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    public static ObservableCollection<InvoiceItem> invoice_items = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceItem>();

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }


public ObservableCollection<InvoiceItem> Invoice_Items
    {
        get
        {
            return invoice_items;
        }
        set
        {
            invoice_items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Invoice_Items");
        }
    }
```

In my `TabItemView.xaml` I have `DataGrid` binded to `InvoiceItem` Collection

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" 
              Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="55,115,55,0" Name="dataGrid1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" CanUserResizeRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding invoice_items}" 
              DataContext="{Binding invoice_items}" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Binding="{Binding Item_Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mesure" Binding="{Binding Mesure}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price exc VAT" Binding="{Binding Price_exc_VAT}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="VAT" Binding="{Binding VAT}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price Inc VAT" Binding="{Binding Price_inc_VAT}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding Total}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This how looks `TabItemView.xaml.cs`

```
    public partial class TabItemView : UserControl
{
    public TabItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = MainViewModel.items;

    }
```

}

I need to bind array index to datagrid row index, because I need to set the Propertie for each Propertie in my `items` array.
I'm guessing it should look like

```
    public string Item_Name
{
    get
    {
        return invoice.items[RowIndex].Item_Name;
    }

    set
    {
        if (invoice.items[RowIndex].Item_Name != value)
        {
            invoice.items[RowIndex].Item_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Item_Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know at what point I need to add a new Item to my items array. I think it should be added when user changes row. But how do I implement this?

Also I tried to see if my databinding to DataGrid is correct and I removed array and left code like this `InvoiceItem items = new InvoiceItem();`And as result my `DataGrid` displayed only one row and I can't add another one. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues going on here, but the first thing I would suggest is to get past the idea of having to interact directly with the DataGrid. You should think of it as a control that is expressing your collection; not something you need to constantly manage directly.

So, I would ask: why do you really need to know the exact index of a specific row? When you have an item selected, you can just look at the SelectedItem in your DataGrid(which you can bind a property to).

Other points:

1. The **Item_Name** property is violating the expected abstraction of MVVM. Your ViewModel cannot know anything about the view in order to properly observe this pattern. Otherwise, this is MVP.
2. Remove `DataContext="{Binding invoice_items}"` from your DataGrid. It's unnecessary.
3. Don't set `dataGrid1.ItemsSource = MainViewModel.items;` in your code behind. The control can handle this in it's binding. In MVVM it's best to not reference controls in codebehind where possible. Instead in your constructor do:

   ```
   this.DataContext = MainViewModel;
   ```

Before you decide to move forward with your design I suggest you study the MVVM pattern more to appreciate it's point and purpose so that you don't run into these issues. I recommend [this MVVM tutorial by Jason Dolinger (Lab49)](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) to anyone who is starting out in MVVM. Though it's from a few years ago it really nails the basics in a way that is easy to understand and I think it can really help you.